# CSS menu - Moving bar: What's wrong?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, slider, nav

I want to implement a moving bar into my navigation for my site, but I'm having some trouble.
As a tutorial, I followed this link (http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/)

This is my result: http://matt-productions.be/berto/index.html

Would anybody be so kind to check what has gone wrong?

Thanks a million!
Matt

Comment: What's the problem? what have you tried? Seems to work on Chrome at this end...

Comment: I've edited my code online, so it works now.
Thanks to @andyb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the CSS is missing for the `#magic-line` since you have a selector called `#MagicLine` in your CSS.

Secondly, the `.hover()` selector is incorrect. It should bind the *hover* event to the menu items' child `<a>` tag `$("#example-one li a").hover(function() {` but you have bound it to the magic-line instead `$("#navMagicLine li a").hover(function() {`. This results in the *width* calculation resulting in the wrong value which makes the magic line being a lot longer than expected.

Fixing those problems *should* correct your menu but in future I'd recommend looking at any example code again or trying to create your own standalone demo. Often I find that in trying to create a demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or another demo site that the problem becomes clear :-)

**Edit:**

Your CSS is still not the same as the demo. The *list items* need to be `display:inline-block` otherwise jQuery will not be able to calculate the `.width()`. *Inline* elements have no width (or height).

CSS needs to be:

```
#navMagicLine li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The `.hover()` needs to be on the `<a>` of **your** menu, not the dynamic line. It needs to be:

```
$("#navMagicLine li a").hover(function() {
    // function body
})
```

Comment: I did all the changes you said (If I understand them correctly).
After changing the CSS, I could see the bar moving above my header (wrong width).

After changing the JS, the bar disappeared. I'm not sure if I did the correct thing, so would you mind checking again?

Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check the demo site you linked in your question as all the answers are there :-)

Comment: It really tought I did everything right, apparantly not...
I'm really glad you took the time to fix my own dumb problem

Thanks!!


Really, thanks

Comment: Happy to help! Usually questions like this get closed so quickly (as they are technically _too localised_) but I think there's a place on stack for this sort of Q&A. If people have time to help then why not allow it? :-)